# JS objects: Why can you change a property by setting variable equal to object, but not by setting it equal to object's property?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following JS code:

```
let a = {
    a1: 1,
    a2: 1,
    a3: 1
}
let b = a
b.a3 = 2
console.log(a) // { a1: 1, a2: 1, a3: 2 }

let d = a.a3
d = 3
console.log(a) // { a1: 1, a2: 1, a3: 2 }
```

With the first `console.log`, I've set `b` to `a`, changed a property on `b`, and seen that it is reflected in `a`.

With the second `console.log`, I've set `d` to a property `a3` of `a`, changed `d`, and seen that it is *not* reflected in `a`.

Why the difference?

Comment: Object (arrays and functions included) are pare passed by reference, other types are passed by value so `b` and `a` hold the same object and `d` is a copy of `a.a3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is when you set `b` to `a`, it is using `b` as a reference to `a` because `a` is an object. When you set `d` to `a.a3`, you are setting `d` to the value of `a.a3` because `a.a3` references a value and not the object itself.

Comment: This answers it. Thanks!